# Google Docs/Apps APIs: Spreadsheets (Google Sheets) with Charts

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to automate the process of creating a chart within a google doc from a .NET application.

The workflow I'm looking for is...

1. Create Excel Document.
2. Upload to Google Docs.
3. **Create charts on the spreadsheet. (Can't figure this out.)**
4. Publish using ACLs. (bonus)

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use the Google Chart API for this or pure Spreadsheet API.

I'm using the GData .NET client library.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Confirmed by a Google employee on the Google forum this is not possible...

Answer (score 2):

**(Jun 2016)** The original accepted answer is now out-of-date. As of Google I/O 2016, you **can** create charts within a Sheet from the Google Sheets API. First things first: 1) [GData APIs](http://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory) are the previous generation of Google APIs... while not all have been deprecated, [all **newer** Google APIs](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis) do **not** use [the Google Data Protocol](http://developers.google.com/gdata); and 2) there is a [new Google Sheets API v4](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2016/05/apps-dev-sheets-api.html) (not GData]).

Moving forward from here, you need to get [the Google APIs Client Library for .NET](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet) and use the latest [Sheets API](http://developers.google.com/sheets), which is much more powerful and flexible than any previous API. Here's a [C# code sample](http://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/dotnet) to help get you started. If you're not allergic to Python, I made [a video](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2016/06/introducing-google-sheets-api-v4.html) introducing the new API and gave a deeper dive into its code via [a blogpost](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/06/using-new-google-sheets-api.html) that you can learn from and effectively migrate to C# if desired. If you're not allergic to JavaScript and want to try a more complex hands-on example, the project in our [Google Sheets codelab](http://g.co/codelabs/sheets) creates a chart and a pivot table using the API. You can then extrapolate how to do this in C#.

With regards to [publishing](http://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-revisions#publishing_revisions) and [sharing/ACLs](http://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing), both are done w/the [Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive) because these are more general operations you can apply to Sheets, Docs, *and* Slides.